# How to allow Azure to access private Github?

Tags: azure, github

So I want to my repository to be private but still allow Azure to access it in order to deploy my website. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You generate a new SSH key-pair and use that key with Azure. This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

Comment: I tried this but I didn't see any steps involving actually connecting my Github to Azure

Answer (score 0):

The documentation "[Azure App Service: Deploying a Bitbucket repo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37844.azure-app-service-deploying-a-bitbucket-repo.aspx)" uses a WebApp,

[image: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-00-05/2843.RunJekyll07.png]

In that application, the deployment steps allows you to grant access to a private repository (the documentation mentions BitBucket, but the process would be similar for GitHub):

[image: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-imagefileviewer/communityserver-wikis-components-files-00-00-00-00-05/3107.RunJekyll08.png_2D00_550x0.png]

> - The Deployment Source blade opens. Click `Configure required settings` and select `Bitbucket` as the source.
> - Authorize Azure to connect to your Bitbucket account by clicking `Grant access`.
>     Click `OK` to complete the authorization process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GitHub Enterprise and not GitStack or some other, you need to get the SSH key for your Web App to populate in GitHub.

To get the key, go to https://[your-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1

Once you've got the key, you need to add it as a Deploy Key to your GitHub Enterprise repository (Settings -> Deploy Keys).  Once you've done this, you need to configure commit notifications using a web hook:

1. In the Azure Portal, go in to your WebApp
2. Select Deployment Credentials
3. Enter a username and password to use for deployments (The portal may say FTP credentials but these can be used over HTTPS too)
4. In GitHub Enterprise, within the same branch you added the SSH key, select Webhooks & Services
5. Populate the Payload URL as https://[username]:[password]@[your-web-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/deploy
6. Content Type is application/json
7. Select "Just the push event" from which events would you like to trigger this webhook
8. Make sure "Active" is ticked and save

Now commit something to your repo, commit and sync and it should deploy to your WebApp.

Answer (score 0):

I use azure spring app; I think it the same procedure as using app service.
go to config server in your azure app portal

- enter your repository url
- select HTTP Basic authentication
- you will need to insert your username and personal token.

to create personal token follow bellow.

[image]

From your github profile go to settings/developer settings/Personal access token.

Create your token.
[image]

Very important to allow the right access for the azure to be able to work.
I myself don't know which access they need, so I allowed them all. but you can do your search or allow one by one if you have a time.
[image]

after that everything will work smoothly.